# How can I find out all sensor my smartphone has?

Tags: applications, sensors

Is there a way to analyse, which characteristics my smartphone is capable of?

I found an app [Z-Device Test](https://market.android.com/details?id=zausan.zdevicetest&hl=en), that claims to be able to analyse these characteristics:

> the GPS signal, camera, compass, accelerometer, microphone,
>   speakers, WiFi signals, Bluetooth, GSM / UMTS, FM Radio, Display,
>   Battery, CPU, Memory, Vibration, USB, Audio / Video , operating
>   system, light sensor, proximity sensor, temperature sensor, flash
>   sensor, NFC near field comunication, Barometer, the detection of Navstar

But that program abuses its system privilege to dump advertisements everywhere, so I don't want to test that one.

Is there a safe way to get the information?

Comment: Guess there are some more apps for sensor testing: [Check My Android](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Check-My-Android/com.checkmyandroid.app) / [AndroSensor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AndroSensor/com.fivasim.androsensor) / [Sensor Test](http://www.appbrain.com/app/it.tenaciousd93.sensortest) / [Android Sensors](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Android-Sensors/org.androidsensors.antoniocoviello.widget) / [Phone Tester (sensors, GPS...)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Phone-Tester-sensors-GPS/com.mtorres.phonetester) / ...

Comment: sure, but I am afraid, they are all spyware? thats, why I asked here, if there is another way. maybe directly on the android terminal?

Comment: Guess that's a bit paranoid: I've heard not all apps on Play are spyware, so there must be one app that's not :) Seriously: Just check their permissions, ratings, download count, and then decide for yourself. // For whether it's possible just via the terminal, I must pass on to someone who can tell. But I doubt that would be easy, without any programming involved, as maybe not all sensors have corresponding command-line tools.